# Drop Down Date Delivery

Tags: asp.net, datetime, drop-down-menu

I want to use a asp.net drop down to present the user a delivery date on checkout. What I'm not sure about is how to get the specific dates. What the user should see and be able to select in the drop down is the next Monday and Tuesday for the next two weeks. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to get the next monday or tuesday at all? Or do you just expect us to give you the answer without you lifting a finger?

Comment: @James Black: if we had anything better to do, we'd be off somewhere doing it.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I just find that people are getting lazy and not trying to solve the problem, so, if we give them the answer then they will never learn how to do it on their own.

Comment: If you already know the answer, I'd hope you'd give it. If you don't want to help, as MusiGenesis says, go do something else.

Comment: I gave some idea as to how to approach it. I am bouncing between reading blogs, this site and working on some php and ASP.NET. :)

Comment: @James: I've gotten to be one of them lazy people, too. I either never knew or forgot how to do day-of-week stuff in .Net, so I would probably just post a question here rather than digging it up myself. Maybe.

Comment: @James: I think you just gave me a great idea. I'm going to try building an entire application just by posting questions on StackOverflow and using nothing but the code samples people post in their answers. I wonder how complex an app I (we) could build that way?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the DateTime.DayOfWeek property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx).

You start with getting today's date, or, if today is Monday and you can't deliver for two days, so the next delivery will be a week Monday, then start with tomorrow. I am not certain how you would handle if I order tomorrow could I get a delivery date for the next day, so I would need that clarified.

Get the day of the week, starting with either today or tomorrow, extracting it from a specific date as explained here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx

If it isn't Monday or Tues then just determine how many days you need to reach Monday or Tuesday, then add that number of days and get that date, and then just add seven and get the date.

I would prefer to let .NET determine the date of seven days from now, as you may change month or years.

That is the basic approach.  If you get stuck when trying to implement it, I would suggest some code so we can help you determine where you got stuck.

There are other approaches, but this is probably the simplest to understand and implement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty simple suggestion using a lot of LINQ:

```
private void LoadDeliveryDays(int period)
{
  DateTime[] days = Enumerable.Range(1, period).Select(i => DateTime.Today.AddDays(i)).ToArray();
  DropDownList1.DataSource = (from d in days where d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday | d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday select d.ToString("dddd dd-MM-yyyy")).ToArray();
  DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

You probably want to change the `d.ToString("dddd dd-MM-yyyy")` and/or what value is actually used in the dropdown.